Tailwind error when installing shadcn in Vite React App
I was setting up shadcn in a React App using Vite by using the following command:
npx shadcn@latest init
and I received an error (please see error below). I had installed tailwind and did setup as mentioned on official website.
npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npx tailwindcss init -p
Error:

No Tailwind CSS configuration found at
/Users/mubashirahmed/Code/shadcn-project.
It is likely you do not have
Tailwind CSS installed or have an invalid configuration.
Install
Tailwind CSS then try again. 
Visit https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite to get started.

What could be the possible reason for that?

So after some search, I found a fix (from GitHub issues of repo) and the fix is quite simple you just have to add tailwind headers to index.css (global css file) of your project.
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

You can see other discussion here as well: https://github.com/shadcn-ui/ui/issues/4677

This worked for me

and note that if you're using sass/scss you have to change your global style file from scss extension to css

@AbolfazlAkbarzadeh thanks. I wanted to ask one more thing, when I copy components from shadcn website into my app, components work but the css is very different. Do you know what could be the reason? By different I mean it seems some of the css is not getting applied properly.

Nevermind, had some issues in config file.

@mubashir maybe, but it's better to install shadcn components by it's cli interface to prevent this kind of issues "npx shadcn add "

Worked for me. I didn't have an index.css file in my project
